# Chrome app - how to reboot app?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, restart

I am creating a Chrome app and I have made a Logout button in the app.

How can I restart/reset the app? (background.js / background page should be restarted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`chrome.runtime` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime) is your friend.

> `chrome.runtime.reload()`
>
> Reloads the app or extension.

Note that this will probably close all windows opened by the app.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about the user experience I'm not sure if `chrome.runtime.reload()` is the best what you can do.
It is far much better if you just create a some king of cleanup function which will release unused resources (user's data I mean). The same thing in the app window. If you are using some framework it is probably easy. But in the end reconsider cleaning up instead of rebooting the app.