# Reboot Chromebox from Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is it possible to reboot a Chromebox  (shutdown machine and restart device) from within a Chrome App?

The closest I have found is restarting the app using chrome.runtime.reload() as explained here:
[Chrome app - how to reboot app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730426/chrome-app-how-to-reboot-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chrome.runtime.restart()`, which only works in kioks apps.

Comment: thanks @Daniel Herr. Anything for shutting down and starting up at a specific time? I have looked at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime but can't see anything